# mysql, subquery or join in group by condition

Tags: mysql

```
+------------+------+-----------------------+
| invoice    | amount |  paid  | date       |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 1001       |  55    |  1     | 2015-01-01 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+ 
| 1002       |  30    |  0     | 2015-02-01 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+ 
| 1003       |  59    |  1     | 2015-02-01 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+ 
| 1004       |  78    |  0     | 2015-03-01 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+ 
| 1005       |  65    |  1     | 2015-03-01 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+ 
| 1006       |  107   |  0     | 2015-04-01 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

For example, if I have above table,
I want to get total invoice amount and paid amount.

for total invoice amount

```
select sum(amount) from invoice group by DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m")
```

to get paid invoice

```
select sum(amount) from invoice where paid=1 group by DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m")
```

How can I combine it into single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` to sum just the rows with `paid = 1`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS month,
       SUM(amount) AS total,
       SUM(IF(paid = 1, amount, 0)) AS total_paid
FROM invoice
GROUP BY month;
```